# Regex in SQL Server, how can i found only certain length of integers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server and a column ( consider the column is of varchar or INT data type), The column has values and most of them are integers.

How can I query only integers with length 3, not more than 3 or less than 3  using Regular Expression?
is it possible in SQL Server?
do I need to install any additional libraries?

Input

### column

1. 123
2. 234
3. 4532
4. 223
5. 2e34
6. 234
7. 22
8. 23344

Expected Output:

### Column

1. 123
2. 234
3. 223
4. 234

Comment: You've tagged [[tag:sql-server]] (and [[tag:sql-server-2012]]) but also [[tag:mysql-regexp]]; the latter is (as the tag suggests) a **MySQL** function, not a T-SQL function. SQL Server *has no* built in T-SQL funtionality. What, however, is wrong with `LEN`..?

Comment: @Larnu I think you meant "SQL Server has no built in Regex functionality"

Comment: I did, @Charlieface .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not have Regex. Even if it did, I wouldn't recommend it here

You can just use a cast and `BETWEEN`

```
WHERE TRY_CAST(YourColumn AS int) BETWEEN 100 AND 999
```

If the column is actually an `int` then you don't even need a cast.

Comment: In before the OP says "I have values like `'012'` too." ;)

Comment: Hi @Charlieface,

I appreciate your answer, Thank you for the answer.
I have few constraints while using Between keyword, I have to automate the data extraction using Python by connecting with SQL Server, Here I have to take the input from user like how much length of integers user required to fetch.
like if user say integer length =3 then script has to fetch all the data in that particular column having length =3.
that is the reason i am looking for Regex based solution

Comment: So you can just pass two parameters `pow(10, YourLength - 1) + 1` and `pow(10, YourLength) - 1` which gives you the same result